# Running Selenium tests on a locally run application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, xunit, .net-framework-version

I'm relatively new to working with Selenium. I'm writing integration tests for a locally run web application. I'm also a little bit new to testing web applications. But here's what I'm having trouble with. I'm running the application by clicking IIS Express for Chrome in visual studio which then grays out the option to run tests in Test Explorer.

I'm assuming there's an obvious silly answer here, but all of my googling and watching YouTube videos has not resulted in any answers.

I'm using writing Selenium in C# with Xunit in .NET Framework.

Comment: You can set the driver to use the same debugger port as VS.  ex: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  So in this case "9222" would be the same port that Visual Studio used to hook in to the browser.

Comment: if using VS 2022 the port should be 4026.  See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022